# Core Data produces Analyzer warnings

Tags: xcode, ios, core-data, clang-static-analyzer

I am doing the final touch ups on an app and I am getting rid of every compiler/analyzer warning.

I have a bunch of Class methods that wrap my apps access to Core Data entities. This is "provoking" the analyzer.

```
+ (CDProductEntity*) newProductEntity {

    return (CDProductEntity*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDProductEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]];
}
```

Which results in an Analyzer warning:

> Object with +0 retain counts returned
>   to caller where a +1 (owning) retain
>   count is expected

In the method that calls the above Class Method I have this:

```
CDProductEntity *newEntity = [self newProductEntity];
```

Which results in an Analyzer warning:

> Method returns an Objective-C object
>   with a +1 retain count (owning
>   reference)

Explicitly releasing or autoreleasing a Core Data entity is usually very very bad, but is that what it is asking me to do here?
First it tells me it has a +0 retain count and that is bad, then it tells me it has a +1 which is also bad.

What can I do to ensure that I am either dealing with a Analyzer hiccup or that I release correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem static analyzer complains about may be in your method name - per obj-c naming conventions methods with alloc, new or copy in their names are expected to return objects that caller 'owns' and must release - and your method returns autoreleased object.

quote from [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1):

> **You own any object you create.**
>    You
>   “create” an object using a method
>   whose name begins with “alloc” or
>   “new” or contains “copy” (for example,
>   alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

So for a start try I'd suggest just removing 'new' from your method name

Comment: Thank you Vladimir:) you are spot on! I simply didn't think and would never have guessed that naming conventions could raise an Analyzer flag. Well, no excuse, I shouldn't have done that. Thanks again.